# Почему у меня не отображается картинка?[ЗАКРЫТО]

Tags: php, link

Здравствуйте!

Есть ссылка вида: `background-image:url('img/teams/<?=$match['team 2']?>.jpg)`[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Когда я перехожу по ней, то правая картинка не отображается: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для проверки я перешел на другую ссылку типа: [image: введите сюда описание изображения] 
И у меня вывело: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> Так вот в чем вопрос: почему именно при переходе именно эта картинка
>   не отображается, хотя "до" все работает нормально

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вместо

```
background-image:url('img/teams/<?=$match['team 2']?>.jpg
```

нужно в блоке ввести

```
<img src="img/teams/<?=$match['team 2']?>.jpg"/>
```

Разница в том, что изображение встроенное тегом `img` является отдельным объектом в DOM страницы. Такие картинки можно масштабировать средствами браузера и позиционировать как `inline-block` объекты. Если же картинку делаете фоном какого-то объекта, то масштабировать её не получится, позиционирование на странице будет наследоваться от родителя